# Read MongoDB array into perl and walk data

Tags: arrays, mongodb, perl, multidimensional-array

I am trying to capture an array from my MongoDB database into my Perl script and read each element.  This is something that I thought would be simple, but for some dumb reason it is kicking my rearend.

My MongoDB Document (in part)

`"members" : [
        "5713b2d46d210e51836de591", 
        "me", 
        "you", 
        "him", 
        "her"
    ],`

Perl code

```
$document = $database -> get_collection('my_collection')->find_one({_id => $oid});
@members = $document->{'members'};  
print Dumper @members;  

foreach $member (@members)  
    {
    print "member = $member\n";
    }
exit;
```

Output I am getting:

> $VAR1 = [
>             '5713b2d46d210e51836de591',
>             'me',
>             'you',
>             'him',
>             'her'
>           ];
>   member = ARRAY(0x47fa398)

Looking at the last line I see that I am being passed a reference to the array instead of the values.  So I tried accessing via $member[0] or $member[1] but that just returns the same ARRAY(0x*****).

PLEASE HELP, I am sure it is something stupid.

Thanks!

Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mongo, but looking at the output, your @members array has one element - an array ref (as you suspected).  Since Mongo is returning an arrayref, you're best to store that in a scalar and access it like so;

```
my $members = $document->{'members'};
print "second item returned is: ", $members->[1];
print "The complete contents:\n";
for my $item ( @$members )  {
    print "  ", $item;
}
```

Comment: Marty, thank you.  I didn't think to try accessing it via scalar.  In my mind it was an array so I was trying to treat it as one.